# Rounding up a time to the nearest hour

Tags: c#, variables, time, split, rounding

ok basically I have a program that is re-writing text files and formatting them through various conditions, one of the conditions is that the date and time values in my original text file needs to be removed from its current location and moved into a new column I have created, this is done with the code below. I used a regex to find the date and time format and then remove it from its current location and store the value in a variable that I can use later...

```
if (line.Contains(date))
{
    string pattern = @"(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s?\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})";
    string input = line;
    string replacement = "";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    date1 = rgx.Match(input).ToString();
    string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
    line = result;
}
```

This new value that is returned gets both the time and date values but only as one string, so I then used a split (shown below) to get the two values separate, now split[0] is my time variable (00/00/00 format) - which I now need to round up to the nearest hour. I am really not sure how to go about this, any ideas ?

```
string[] split = date1.Split(' ');                
writer.WriteLine(split[0] + "\t" + split[1] + "\t" + line);
```

Comment: What's your criteria for rounding down ?

Comment: its just whichever hour the minutes are closet too e.g 10:35:10 would be 11:00:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get that date from the string into a DateTime struct. See for example the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method

Then you can create a new DateTime value, based on year/month/day/hour of the value from the previous step, setting the minute and second parts to zero (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130.aspx) )

Add one hour if the minutes or seconds part (of your first value) is not zero, using [.AddHours(1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx), which returns a new DateTime value.

**EDIT**
Some sample code:

```
string inputdate = "2:56:30 8/7/2014";

DateTime dt;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo enUS = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputdate, "H:m:s d/M/yyyy", // hours:minutes:seconds day/month/year
    enUS, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
  // 'dt' contains the parsed date: "8-7-2014 02:56:30"
  DateTime rounded = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, 0, 0);
  if (dt.Minute > 0 || dt.Second > 0) // or just check dt.Minute >= 30 for regular rounding
    rounded = rounded.AddHours(1);

  // 'rounded' now contains the date rounded up: "8-7-2014 03:00:00"
}
else
{
  // not a correct date
}
```

Comment: I can see the logic but still having issues with the code, could you further assist with code ?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I need to round it to lower hour, and I used this logic:

```
DateTime x = new DateTime();
x = x.Date.AddHours(x.Hour);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try one liner solution to convert your `DateTime` to nearest hour,

```
//Input DateTime
DateTime input = DateTime.ParseExact("28/05/2021 2:16 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//Ternary Operation
var output = input.Minute > 30  //Check if mins are greater than 30
       ? input.AddHours(1).AddMinutes(-input.Minute) //if yes, then add one hour and set mins to zero
       : input.AddMinutes(-input.Minute); //otherwise set mins to zero

Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Try Online: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/53yZjw)

Answer (score 1):

In C#

```
var Now = DateTime.Now;
var Nearest = Now.Date;
Nearest = Nearest.AddHours(Now.Hour + (Now.Minute >= 30 ? 1 : 0));
```

`Now` = Current time

`Nearest` = Rounded to the nearest hour

Comment: Please add at least a short explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert the string to a datetime?

Something like:

```
dateVariable = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
int hour = dateVariable.Hour;
int minute = dateVariable.Minute;
```

And then do the rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Now as you have

```
            string[] str = split[1].Split('/');
            // create a new DateTime
            int minutes = int.Parse(str[1]);
            if(minutes >= 30)
                  hour = int.Parse(str[0]) + 1 // make sure if it 13 or 25 make it 1
                  minutes = 0 ;
                  sec = 0;
            else {
                 hour = int.Parse(str[0]);
                 minutes = 0 ;
                 sec = 0 ;
            }
            var myDate = new Date(Year, month , day , hour , minutes , sec);
```

Comment: Why not start with DateTime.Parse/ParseExact, then do the logic for rounding?